# Match image tag not nested in an anchor tag using regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How would I match images that is not nested inside an anchor tag using regular expression?

Here is what I want:

**No match:** `<a href="index.html"><img src="images/default.jpg" /></a>`

**Match:** `<div><img src="images/default.jpg" /></div>`

**Match:** `<img src="images/default.jpg" />`

I'm no good at regex but this is what I came up so far, which doesn't work:

`[^<a[^>]*>]<img.*?/>[^</a>]`

I couldn't use lookarounds since PHP wants it to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the reason behind your difficulty is simply that HTML is not a regular language, see: [Coding Horror: Parsing Html the Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Consider using a query expression language powerful enough to process (X)HTML, or just using the DOM programmatically to fetch all image tags and then exclude those with `<a>` ancestors.

In PHP5, I believe you can use `DOMXPath`, using that it becomes as simple as:

```
$generated_string = '<a href="index.html"><img src="images/inside_a.jpg" /></a>' .
                    '<div><img src="images/inside_div.jpg" /></div>' .
                    '<img src="images/inside_nothing.jpg" />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($generated_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[not(self::a)]/img");

foreach ($elements as $element){
  echo $doc->saveXML($element) . "\n";
}
```

This code would give the output:

```
<img src="images/inside_div.jpg"/>
<img src="images/inside_nothing.jpg"/>
```

Comment: The html content is from a generated string not a file.

Comment: Not a problem, use ``$doc->loadHTML($generated_string)`` in that case.

Comment: Updated my example for operating on a string instead of an HTML file

Answer (score -1):

`<img[^>]*>(?![^<]*</a>)`